# How to change value of element in FOR loop

Tags: symfony, twig

How i can change value of element in For loop, eg.

I have table of Elements like this:

```
Id. Name
1.  Element1
2.  Element2
3.  Element3
```

And in Twig, after I fetch collection of this elements, I want to display it all in loop:

```
{% for element in elements %}
    {{element.id}}
    {{element.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

But for Element1 i want to display it name like: 'Ele'.

So how I can modify displayed element in situation like above?

Comment: so you want to display only first three letters of the name? only for the first one?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I just gave an example. I want to change displayed name of specific element. It could be 'Component1' instead of Element1 or Ele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should read Twig's `for` [document](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable).

In your situation, my suggestion is:
Use `loop.index` if your index start with 1 and `loop.index0` if start with 0

```
{% for element in elements %}
    {{element.id}}
    {{ loop.index == 1 ? 'Ele' : element.name }}
{% endfor %}

{# OR #}

{% for element in elements %}
    {{element.id}}
    {{ loop.index0 == 0 ? 'Ele' : element.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: So what if `Element1` is at the `x`'th position?

Comment: @DarkBee in that situation, you should use a key of the element(like `element.id`) to check. I provide a way of using `for` loop's special variables. If you know the element's position, you can use with `loop.index`, otherwise, use the element's key